# how to calcualate how many hours between now and a time

Tags: python, datetime, tkinter

i'm trying to make a timer that can shows how many hours and minutes between now and a specify time and display it with tkinter,i want the timer update every seconds,i'm new to python i dont really know how to do it

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Label
now = datetime.now
time = "09:00:00"
FMT = "%H:%M:%S"
timedelta = datetime.strptime(now, FMT) - datetime.strptime(time, FMT)
print(timedelta)
main = tk.Tk()
main.title("timer")
lb=Label(text=timedelta)
lb.pack()
main.mainloop()
```

i make alot of mistake on this script as well

Comment: You did not call `datetime.now`. Add `()`!

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/jerry/Desktop/python saves/timer/test.py", line 8, in <module> 
    timedelta = datetime.strptime(now, FMT) - datetime.strptime(time, FMT)
TypeError: must be str, not datetime.datetime

Comment: i have an error

Comment: some notes: l.5 - `datetime.now()`, don't forget the brackets. / l.6 - you specify a time but no date / l.7 - you overwrite an import, namely `timedelta`, and your variable `now` is a `datetime` object, not a string so `datetime.strptime` cannot be called on that.

Answer (score 2):

I think this might help - [How to calculate number of days between two given dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151199/how-to-calculate-number-of-days-between-two-given-dates) or this - [How do I find the time difference between two datetime objects in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345827/how-do-i-find-the-time-difference-between-two-datetime-objects-in-python) or maybe this - [Measuring elapsed time with the Time module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620943/measuring-elapsed-time-with-the-time-module)
I tried, and made this:

```
import datetime
from datetime import date

today = datetime.date.today()
yourday = datetime.date(2020, 7, 15)
timebeetwen = today - yourday
print(timebeetwen.days*24) #hours
print(timebeetwen.days*24*60) #minutes
print(timebeetwen.days*24*60*60) #seconds
```

Datetime works only with days so the output will be like this:

```
>>> 48
>>> 2880
>>> 172800
```

And if you want to show every second use

```
while True:
    print(timebeetwen.days*24) #hours
    print(timebeetwen.days*24*60) #minutes
    print(timebeetwen.days*24*60*60) #seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

So I find another answer. Here is the link - [How to make a timer program in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15802554/how-to-make-a-timer-program-in-python)
And here is the code:

```
import time
# Ask to Begin
#start = input("Would you like to begin Timing? (y/n): ")
#if start == "y":
timeLoop = True

# Variables to keep track and display
Sec = 0
Min = 0
# Begin Process
#timeLoop = start
while timeLoop:
    Sec += 1
    print(str(Min) + " Mins " + str(Sec) + " Sec ")
    time.sleep(1)
    if Sec == 60:
        Sec = 0
        Min += 1
        print(str(Min) + " Minute")
```

This is like a timer. It counts every second as you need